# how does branching works , using the gitflow workflow?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-flow

I am working on a project and we are using gitflow workflow. Basically I am just new to gitflow workflow , I have just a question.

There were two branches from the repository which is the master and the development branch . I checked out the development remote branch since This branch will contain the complete history of the project.

Now I wanted to get the updates from the team the latest one ,should I pull it from the master branch ? or in the development branch ?

Another thing if i push my changes , should i push my changes on origin/master ? or origin development ?

By the way all of us developers checked out the development branch remotely. using the command
git checkout -b development origin/development

Bear with me just new to git workflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I wanted to get the updates from the team the latest one ,should I
>   pull it from the master branch ? or in the development branch?

All of your team mates changes should be in the `develop` branch.

> Another thing if i push my changes , should i push my changes on
>   origin/master ? or origin development?

Your standard work-flow should be to create a `feature` branch off `develop`, and then merge this back into `develop` when your feature is complete.  Periodically (many agile teams align this with their sprint cadence) you'll create a `release` branch off `develop` and merge this branch into `master`, thereby releasing all of the code that's in your `develop` branch.

Finally if you have an urgent issue that you need to fix (e.g. a live bug) then you'll want to create a `hotfix` branch off `master` and merge this into `master` and down into `develop`.

Returning to your original question: if your team mates all follow this work flow too then you should see that all of your team mates changes should be in the `develop` branch on your remote.

For more reading about Git Flow: https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Edit: when you do a release you also need to merge your `release` branch back down into `develop`.